# R2DBC Postgres SQL Enum Issue

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

As part of learning r2DBC i have come across an issue facing with Enum conversion. I am using PostgreSQL here.
When reading data for Film where rating is ***PG-13 and NC-17( anything with dash )*** i am facing issues.

Below is my schema for table

```
create table film
(
film_id          integer       default nextval('film_film_id_seq'::regclass) not null
    constraint film_pkey
        primary key,
title            varchar(255)                                                not null,
description      text,
release_year     year,
language_id      smallint                                                    not null
    constraint film_language_id_fkey
        references language
        on update cascade on delete restrict,
rental_duration  smallint      default 3                                     not null,
rental_rate      numeric(4, 2) default 4.99                                  not null,
length           smallint,
replacement_cost numeric(5, 2) default 19.99                                 not null,
rating           mpaa_rating   default 'G'::mpaa_rating,
last_update      timestamp     default now()                                 not null,
special_features text[]
);
```

And the mpaa_rating is defined as

```
create type mpaa_rating as enum ('G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NC-17');
```

This is my code which registers the converters in my Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
@EnableR2dbcAuditing
public class DVDRentalDBConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    System.out.println("Initializing postgreSQL connection factory");
    return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
            PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .database("dvdrental")
                    .username("postgres")
                    .password("postgres")
                    .codecRegistrar(EnumCodec.builder().withEnum("mpaa_rating", Rating.class).build())
                    .build()
    );
}

@Override
protected List<Object> getCustomConverters() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new RatingWritingConverter());
}

@Bean
ReactiveTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    System.out.println("Initializing postgreSQL connection factory");
    return new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}
}
```

My code for retrieving is pretty simple

```
 private Mono<FilmModel> getFilmById(Long id) {
    return filmRepository.findById(id).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(DataFormatException::new));
}
```

Adding the exception which is thrown https://gist.github.com/harryalto/bd51bbcdd081868c5064c808d08205e4

I tried researching stack overflow but couldn't figure out the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you add the exception.

Comment: added the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot/Spring Data R2dbc to map table to POJO, you can skip the enum definition in Postgres, by default Spring Data R2dbc will handle the enum as varchar/char in db side, and use Enum in java POJO, check [my example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot), and [schema sql script](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/resources/schema.sql) and [mapped entity class](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L440-L481). Spring Boot registered mapping converter to convert them automatically.

If you would like to handle the Enum type yourself, check [this example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/data-r2dbc-repositories).

Comment: the issue i am facing is something to do with reverse lookup for enums which is the actual problem. I have already looked at the links you have shared( thanks for the details and examples). But i dont think this would resolve the problem i am facing.

Comment: Understand your satiation,  you can try to create your own `EnumCodec` instead of the built-in one to resolve this issue.

Comment: I exactly did that and now able to resolve the issue. Thanks @Hantsy